# Two classes to use the same function to create custom view - Swift

Tags: swift, class, protocols, extension-methods

I am kind of new to Swift and I can't figure this out. I have two classes where I need to use the same function to set up a custom UIStackVIew (Rating Control that shows rating stars). Each class has a variable called `value` that needs to be passed inside the function. I don't want to be duplicating the same code of the setUpStackView function inside each class. I have the following code:

```
class Class1: UIStackView {

    var variable1 = "value1"

    override init(frame: CGRect){
      super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    setUpStackView(value: variable1)

}

class Class2: UIStackView {

    var variable2 = "value2"

    override init(frame: CGRect){
      super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    setUpStackView(value: variable2)

}




extension Class1 {

  func setUpStackView(value: String){
    //code to set UIStackView rating control and to use the variable value
  }

}
```

How can I implement the extension for the `Class2`? I am stuck with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just make Class2 be a subclass of Class1? `class Class2: Class1 {...` instead of `class Class2: UIStackView {...`

Comment: How would I pass the variable into the Class2? When I try this, I include `var value = "variable2` and I get an error Cannot override with a stored property value.  Do I need to set a global variable in order to do it?

Comment: You have access to value within Class2. You can just change its value below the `super.init`s in the initializers

Comment: There are several ways to do this - in fact, both answers work, plus again, about 4-5 more. But based on the code you have, why not create a *single* class? In your code, `Class1` - and then just use it? Obviously, you haven't shown how you intend to (which is very important). But really, get rid of `Class2` and declare instances of `Class1` as you wish - using `setUpStackView` where needed, and don't use it where not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution can be moved common code to protocol where you can abstract out:

```
protocol  BaseStackView {
    var variable :String { get set }
}

class Class1: UIStackView,BaseStackView {



    var variable = "value1"

    override init(frame: CGRect){
      super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setUpStackView(value: variable)

    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.setUpStackView(value: variable)
    }
}

class Class2: UIStackView,BaseStackView {

    var variable = "value2"

    override init(frame: CGRect){
      super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setUpStackView(value: variable)
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.setUpStackView(value: variable)
    }



}



extension UIStackView {
    func setUpStackView(value: String) {
        //Your setup here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many options.

You can make Class2 inherit from Class1:

```
class Class2: Class1 {
    var value = "value2" //You have access to Class1's value, so you can change it here
    setUpStackView(value: value) //But there's a problem here
}
```

But you can't just call a function when you're in the middle of a class declaration.
But you can do this in the initializer:

```
class Class2: Class1 {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        value = "value2" 
        setUpStackView(value: value) 
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        value = "value2"
        setUpStackView(value: value) 
    }
}
```

The above is kind of jank because you're referencing class properties within its own initializer.
Here's another solution:

You can make your setup function a function extension of UIStackView:

```
extension UIStackView {
    func setUpStackView(value: String) { 
        //Your setup here
        self.someProperty = value //self is referring to the stackview itself
    }
}
```

Another option is to create a static function.

```
extension Class1 {
    static func setUpStackView(stackVw: UIStackView, value: String) {
        stackVw.someProperty = value 
        //Doing it like this still makes this function "belong" to Class1
        //It also makes it so anyone can set up their stack view like
        //this because they have to pass their stack view in here
    }
}
```

Usage would be like this regardless of what class you're in and what inheritance hierarchy you have:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    Class1.setUpStackVw(stackVw: self, value: self.variable)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    Class1.setUpStackVw(stackVw: self, value: self.variable)
}
```

Yet another option is to create a protocol from which both Class1 and Class2 conform to.

```
protocol StackVwWithSpecialSetUp where Self: UIStackView {
    var value: String {get}
}
extension StackVwWithSpecialSetUp {
    func setUpStackView() 
    {
        self.someProperty = self.value
    }
}
```

And then you'd have your class conform to it

```
class Class1Or2: UIStackView, StackVwWithSpecialSetUp {
    var value: String = "blah" //Compiler will force you to implement this
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        //Now you can use this
        setUpStackVw()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        //You can use this here too
        setUpStackVw()
    }
}
```

Perhaps the way I'd do it is to just eliminate the need for the `value` property altogether:

```
class Class1: UIStackView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpStackVw()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setUpStackVw()
    }

    func setUpStackVw()
    {
        self.accessibilityHint = "value1"
    }
}

//////////

class Class2: Class1 {
    override func setUpStackVw()
    {
        self.someProperty = "value2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I still need to have the Class1 and Class2 with the variables `value` in them? Sorry, I'm kind of new to Swift.

Comment: You can do whatever you want. If you want `value` to be a class property then you can have it be so. If you want Class2 to inherit from Class1, you can just use Class 1's `value`.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you so much!